# Galleon not showing delegation addresses

Tags: delegating, galleon

I delegated to several bakers and when I open my Galleon wallet I can only see my manager address. And all the delegated addresses I created have a scroll kind of charging and says "preparing new address". I did this operation 3 days ago and can see the originations on Tzscan.io Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot please?

Answer (score 5):

What version of Galleon were you using when you did these operations? If you were using an older version, it is possible that the gas/storage limit or the required min fee was not compatible with protocol 003.

Upgrading your wallet to v0.7.0b (https://github.com/Cryptonomic/Deployments/wiki/Galleon:-Releases) and trying the same operations again should fix all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently. Opened it up and no delegated addresses, I thought everything was gone! Downloaded the new version, opened my wallet, and everything was there. Seems like a really weird way to handle software on Galleon's part...

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the latest version from the official Galleon website, I go into the wallet and not all addresses of my delegation are displayed, I go to tezblock and enter my wallet address, All my delegations are displayed there, how to solve this problem?